# .NET SqlCommand ExecuteScalar Is Always 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, executescalar

C# SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() seems to always result in an object with value 0.  Using SQL Server 2012.  This is happening with all stored procedures.  Here is a very simple example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_IsUnitPackaged] 
    @Serial varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT COUNT(serial_number)
    FROM dbo.t_pql_contents
    WHERE serial_number = @Serial
END
GO
```

When I execute this directly in SSMS with a known existing value supplied for @Serial, I get the expected results:

```
(No column name)
1

Return Value
0
```

When I execute in my C# app with the following code, the `result` below is always 0:

```
string unit_serial = "something"; // The same known existing value
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_IsUnitPackaged");
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Serial", SqlDbType.VarChar)
{
    Value = unit_serial,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Size = 20
});

int result = 0;
using (SqlConnection conn = Utils.CONN) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using (comm)
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        Int32.TryParse(comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out result);
    }
}
```

I've seen some other questions asked very similar to this.  The best answer I could find seemed to indicate that it is important that you not structure your stored procedure with a `RETURN` statement when you are expecting to use it with `ExecuteScalar`.  As you can see, I'm not.

So, what am I missing here?

---

UPDATE:  I've also tried adding a `RETURN 0` statement to the end of my procedure so that I only have one result when executing in SSMS:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_IsUnitPackaged] 
    @Serial varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT COUNT(serial_number)
    FROM dbo.t_pql_contents
    WHERE serial_number = @Serial
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

Executing this in SSMS gives only the following result now:

```
(No column name)
1
```

This update to the procedure continues to give a scalar result of 0 in my app, though.

Comment: Your result shows that you get two values from your query.  I believe you should be adding the return statement to your procedures.  Without that your procedure returns 0 as a scalar function.

Comment: Could it be that no row is found? Comment out the WHERE clause to make sure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Can you verify that `TryParse` is returning `true` or `false`?

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the tip!

Comment: @juharr it returns true.  no exceptions.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond Please see my update in response to your comment.

Comment: drop the return 0 that is where the 0 is coming from.

Comment: @Solipcyst you just repeated what you already said. This does not add anything to answer my request. Comment out the WHERE clause as requested to make sure.

Comment: @usr I was trying to say that I did what you asked and a row was still found.  (Only now, the value reflects the total count of all rows in that table -- as expected -- since the where clause is missing.)  The ExecuteScalar result continues to be 0.  This is with or without a `RETURN 0` statement in the procedure.

Comment: @DanielA.White I only added the `RETURN 0` to satisfy a suggestion made by another user.  My original procedure does not have it.

Comment: So if you comment out the where clause and ExecuteScalar returns 0 that tells you that ExecuteScalar does not receive the result of the query at all.

Comment: Actually, please fix the TryParse which has been pointed out to be broken. Use `(int)`. Update the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp.  As @usr pointed out in the comments (followed as well by @AlexHn.), it turned out to be a silly user error.  I couldn't quite wrap my head around what they were asking me to do at first for some reason.  Once I did, it became clear that I had set the value of my parameter incorrectly and so it was in fact returning an accurate result of 0.

Many apologies to all!

[I wasn't sure what etiquette dictates here on SO.  As @usr pointed out, there was no real answer submitted -- only suggestions to help me find the answer myself.  If anyone deserves a check, it's @usr.]

Comment: Best course of action is to delete the question I think.

Comment: @usr Noted.  I can't delete it because it has answers.  Flagging for moderator to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Update your query as below, still if you could not see 5 as result, then there is some issue in your C# code, otherwise issue in your query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_IsUnitPackaged] 
    @Serial varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 5
    FROM dbo.t_pql_contents
END
GO
```

Comment: This is exactly the debugging technique that I have requested in the comments. The result is, there is something wrong with the client code :) But still, this is not an answer but a comment.